# Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal. while running Python Script

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, ssh, subprocess

I'm running below command

```
subprocess.Popen('sshpass -p "Kn0od!e" ssh -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no deceapp@{0} grep -v {1} /opt/jetty_coordinator/jetty/logs/dece* '.format(machineName,grepString), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
```

where machinename is my hostname of machine.But getting below error as

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

Comment: I tried as ssh -o -t -t as well still not get resolved

Comment: What is your question?  Does passing stdin=xxx possible help?