# gradle and "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal"

Tags: gradle, ssh, terminal, stdin, pty

I wrote a perl script executing

```
ssh -t someuser@somehost somecommand
```

where `-t` allows me to enter a password to the remotely executed `somecommand`. Now I need to use the script from gradle and I get

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal
```

I've tried the `-tt` option, and it allowed me to run the command, but nothing gets passed to the remote process.

I guess, my problem is just like [this unanswered python question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26075997/581205).

*How can I execute a script from gradle so that it allows me to pass a password to a remote process (which works fine, when the script gets executed from the command line)?*

## The output

```
> Task :overwriteDb
An output line produced by my script

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Enter password: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user ...
```

After the output from my script, `ssh` seems to complain. The remove database prompts for the password and immediately continues and complains.

When using `ssh -tt` instead of `ssh -t` leads to no warning and no follow-up line; the process just hangs forever.

Comment: who reported the error "*Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal*"?

Comment: @EmilyE. All I know for sure, it wasn't me. :D It must be `ssh`, see my edit. I guess, the subprocess running my script don't properly inherit the `stdin` file descriptor and get some Java-ish emulation instead.